# Degree of splitting field divides n!

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

> If $f\in K[x]$ has degree $n$ over $f$, and $F$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$ then, show that $[F:K]\mid n!$

I can show that $[F:K] \leq n!$ using the fact that 
$[F(a,b):K]\leq [F(a)(b):F(a)][F(a):F]$

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here the solution for the case $char K=0$. In this case, $F$ is a normal and hence a Galois extension of $K$. So, $|Gal(F/K)|=[F:K]$ and the Galois group can be thought of as a subgroup of $S_n$ which has order $n!$ and hence the result follows.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1017341/121097) contains the same proof as the one you just posted.