# Galois theory : verification of degree of splitting field

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, splitting-field

This semester I am doing my Bachelor project which is about "computing the degree of the splitting field of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$".

I have successively written a program which computes such a degree for any polynomial but there is always a chance of failing since I proceed as follows:

- Calculate $f(x)$'s roots $\alpha_1 , ..., \alpha_n$
- Pick random coefficients $\beta_1, ..., \beta_n \in \{1,...,N\}$ and define $\alpha = \beta_1\alpha_1 + ... + \beta_n\alpha_n$
- Using the proof of the **primitive element theorem** we know that as $N\to\infty$ the probability of $\alpha$ being a primitive element of the splitting field goes to $1$.
- Compute the minimal polynomial of the chosen primitive element and we are done.

Here is my question :

Suppose my algorithm outputs a potential degree of the splitting field of $f(x)$, how can I verify with certainty that this degree is correct? That is without using any of my previous work but just in general.

Thanks!

PS: I in fact calculate approximations of $f(x)$'s roots and use the LLL-algorithm to compute minimal polynomials but this isn't relevant here.

Comment: I believe this to be a "computationally hard" problem. As far as I know, the best you can do is that the degree of the splitting field divides $n!$, where $n$ is the degree of $f(x)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259735/degree-of-splitting-field-divides-n)

Comment: This is helpful, thank you !

Comment: The proof of the primitive element theorem is effective, so you can determine which values of $\beta_i$ won't give you a primitive element, and then just make some other choice of parameters.