# if $K$ is the splitting field for $f(x)$ over $F$ and $deg f(x) = n$, then $[K:F] \leq n!$

Tags: galois-theory

I need some help understanding this proof/filling in the details.

I have the following:

We know in general that $[K:F] = [K:K_1][K_1:F]$ but $[K_1:F] = deg(h(x)) \leq n$ (if we consider $K_1$ the splitting field for some $h(x)$.

Apply induction.

$K$ is the splitting field for $f_1(x)$ over $K_1$, and $f_1(x)$ has degree
$n − 1$, so its degree is at most $(n − 1)!$.

I'm not sure how this induction works.  I assume we're using strong-induction.  I would appreciate it if somebody helped me fill in the details of the proof.

Comment: There’s nothing deep about it. Start with $f$ of degree $n$, and find a root $\rho$, giving a field of degree $\le n$ and $f(X)=(X-\rho)f_1(X)$, where the degree of $f_1$ is $n-1$. So the degree of $f_m$ is $n-m$, etc. You should just try it with an $f$ that you know to be irreducible, like $f(X)=X^4+4X+2$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017331, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62762